# SharePoint 2007 workflow email out of the box notice customization

Tags: sharepoint, email, workflow

Is there a file that we can change (xml or otherwise) to change the default format for email notificaitons for workflow notices?

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the Below links on how to customize the Email Alert

[Alert email Template](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx) Or [Custom WorkFlow email](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/3fa216d2-5266-42da-b972-af5b4f255185)